# How can I add a key to an account after creation, e.g. for multisig contract, using near shell, near repl or near-api-js?

Tags: security, blockchain, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

Recently I made an account and deployed a multisig contract that required 2 confirmations (signatures) but I only had 1 full access key. I couldn't do anything with the contract, including setting the number of confirmations to 1... How would I add a key using near shell, near repl or near-api-js?

e.g.

```
near create_account msig --masterAccount account.testnet --initialBalance 50
near deploy --accountId msig --wasmFile ./contract/res/multisig.wasm
near call msig new '{"num_confirmations":2}' --account_id msig
```

At this point the multisig is deployed and instantiated with `num_confirmations = 2`, but there is only 1 key. The full access account key.

How would I add another key so I can confirm multisig requests?

Answer (score 0):

First I have to generate a new key to add to the account. I'm going to name the key `msig.lak1`, for adding a new limited access key (LAK) to my account `msig`:

```
near generate-key msig.lak1
```

Copy the public key that's generated.

For reference and signing txs later, like `confirm` on the multisig contract, the secretKey can be found here: `code ~/.near-credentials/default/msig.lak1.json`

Now I need to add this to the account `msig`.

Given that near shell does not provide the functionality to add a new key to an account, I will have to use near repl.

Launch `near repl` with the accountId `msig` for my multisig contract account with only 1 full access key.

```
near repl --accountId msig
>
```

**Update**: (thanks @vlad-grichina comment)

```
await account.addKey("PUBLIC KEY FROM GENERATE KEY", contractName, 'confirm')
```

Since this is a single action tx.

**Previous**: (if bundling actions)

Now I will create an `addKey` transaction and sign it using the `msig` account.

```
const contractName = "msig"
const result = account.signAndSendTransaction('msig', [
    nearAPI.transactions.addKey(nearAPI.utils.PublicKey.from("PUBLIC KEY FROM GENERATE KEY"), nearAPI.transactions.functionCallAccessKey(contractName, ['confirm'], null)),
])
```

I can verify using near shell that the key is added:

```
near keys msig
```

And now I can use the secret key to confirm a multisig contract request:

```
// in my JS app
await window.keyStore.setKey(
    NETWORK_ID, contractName,
    // from ~/.near-credentials/default/msig.lak1.json
    nearApi.KeyPair.fromString(secretKey)
)
const contract = new nearApi.Contract(window.contractAccount, contractName, {
    changeMethods: ['confirm'],
    sender: contractName
})
...
contract.confirm({ request_id: X }) // confirms request
```

I can also check in the explorer and see that the add access key tx was successful:
https://explorer.testnet.near.org/accounts/msig
[image: add access key image from explorer]

Comment: `await account.addKey("PUBLIC KEY FROM GENERATE KEY", contractName, 'confirm')`

Should be enough to add key in `near repl`